# Does 14' Audi S4 (B8.5) have rear brake pad wear sensors?

Tags: brakes, audi, brake-pad, s4

I am shopping for new rear brake pads for my 14' Audi s4 b8.5 and cannot find any information on the rear brake pad wear sensors. To my knowledge, the front ones had these sensors and I had to purchase them when I changed my front brake pads.

Does my car even have the rear brake pad wear sensors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear the rear brake pads do not have the sensors. Here are a couple of images from RockAuto.com showing the front, then the rear pads:

[image]

[image]

You'll notice in the first picture the wire/sensor and the slots in the brake pads to put the wire/sensor. You don't see any provision for it in the rear brake pads.